# Running vscode source code - downloading ripgrep failed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to download and run VSCode locally following: [VScode Open Source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute), doing the mandatory steps and running it with the folling instructions:

```
cd vscode
yarn
```

I get this error regarding `ripgrep download`:

```
Downloading ripgrep failed: Error: Command failed: powershell \"[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/ripgrep-prebuilt/releases/assets/45984165 -UseBasicParsing -OutFile C:\x\x\x\Local\Temp\vscode-ripgrep-cache-1.12.1\ripgrep-v13.0.0-2-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip -Headers @{\"accept\"=\"application/octet-stream\"} -UserAgent vscode-ripgrep"
```

The package.json

```
   "vscode-ripgrep": "^1.12.1",
```

The yarn.lock

```
vscode-ripgrep@^1.12.1:
  version "1.12.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/vscode-ripgrep/-/vscode-ripgrep-1.12.1.tgz#4a319809d4010ea230659ce605fddacd1e36a589"
  integrity sha512-4edKlcXNSKdC9mIQmQ9Wl25v0SF5DOK31JlvKHKHYV4co0V2MjI9pbDPdmogwbtiykz+kFV/cKnZH2TgssEasQ==
  dependencies:
    https-proxy-agent "^4.0.0"
    proxy-from-env "^1.1.0"
```

I have read some other answers but they all agree with a deprecated `ripgrep` version, it was issued and VSCode has already fix the issue, apparently none has published questions or issues since then.